# ¿Cómo puedo descargar esta documentación completa desde esta dirección web?

Tags: html, web, git, svn, hack

¿Puedo descargar esto de alguna manera o no?

- [esta página](https://docs.blender.org/api/)
- [blender_python_api](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba pensando en algo como descargar con git o svn o alguna línea de comandos en Linux que me permita restar el contenido completo de esa documentación.

Comment: En este caso concreto puedes descargar todo en un zip: https://docs.blender.org/api/master/blender_python_reference_2_80_74.zip En un caso más general [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) es una herramienta que te permite descargar páginas web, y seguir recursivamente los enlaces para bajarlo todo (aunque dar con las opciones adecuadas no es trivial)

Comment: gracias, si me sirvio bastante, fue un descuido mio no haber distinguido que era un link en la documentación